# Can you identify these railings?

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone identify the railings around [this building](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/8d4d81c3-15fc-4eb1-b619-0639d3c47bc4)?
I thought they might be ladders placed horizontally, but I don't see any clips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be either [Fence 1 x 4 x 2 Spindled with 2 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30055#T=C)

[image]

Or [Fence 1 x 4 x 2 Spindled with 4 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15332#T=C)

[image]